# how to change xyz@abc where i need to change xyz when terminal starts

Tags: command-line, hostname

Every time I open my terminal, I see xyz@abc where I type my sudo commands.However, my concern is this xyz and I want to change it to the name of my choice. I am unaware of the technical term for this and also the steps to do this.I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: xyz is your username.

Answer (score 1):

What you see (`xyz@abc`) is the bash prompt:

- `xyz` is the username
- `abc` is the hostname

You can tune it by modifying the variable `PS1` in the file `~/.bashrc`. You may see the Ubuntu documentation: [Customizing Bash Prompt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt).

Simply open `~/.bashrc` file in a text editor like `nano`, create new line filled with a copy of the PS1 definition. For your need, you will replace the `\u` username tag by `coco` if you want to see *coco* in place of *xyz*.

Inside of `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]coco@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}coco@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Some readings:

- [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)
- [.bashrc PS1 generator](http://bashrcgenerator.com/)